# Question about UIWebview and Universal Application

Tags: iphone, html, uiwebview, universal

I have an Universal Application and my question is, if it is possible to load two different html files in my UIWebview depending on the iDevice.

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use this...

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)//if device is ipad
{

}
else   //if device is iPhone
{


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIDevice class.

```
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];    

if ([device.model isEqualToString:@"iPad"])
{

}
else
{
}
```