# trouble setting too many outlets?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

Actually I am converting an iPhone app to iPad.

For that I need to resize the "FONTS" of the labels.

There are many "title" called labels.

So, What I am doing now taking outlets of every label and setting the size of a font when the device is iPad.

There are too many labels so,
1) is there any way to set multiple outlets. to single instance so if I change one instance reflect to all?

2) is there any other method to change the size.

- This is how my code looks like.

  ```
  if([self isPad])
      {
          [btnReset.titleLabel setFont:BUTTON_FONT_iPAD_BOLD];
          [btnViewReport.titleLabel setFont:BUTTON_FONT_iPAD_BOLD];
          scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(768,1200);
  //         scrollEmpView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(768, 1690);
  //        
  //        //Report View Page Frame Set
  //        //Values Before ADDED...
  //        [lblPayeCalculation setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblTaxcode setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblDeduct setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        
  //        [lblPayroll setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblChild setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        
  //        [lblDate setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblFrequency setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblSalary setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        
  //        [lblGross setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblEarnerLevy setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblChildDeduct setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblStudent setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        
  //        [lblKiwiDeduct setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblTaxCredit setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblNetPayment setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblPayrollDonationAmt setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblNetPaymentLessPayroll setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        
  //        [lblPayeCalculation setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        
  //        
  //        
  //        //Values Added...to only set it
  //        
  //        [lblQPaye setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD];
  //        [lblQPaye2 setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblQP1 setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblQP2 setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblQP3 setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblQP4 setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblQPay setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD];
  //        
  //        [lblQPay1 setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblQPay2 setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblQPay3 setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblQCalculation setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD];
  //        [lblQC1 setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblQC2 setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblQC2Sign setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblQC3 setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblQC3Sign setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblQC4 setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblQCSign4 setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblQC5 setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblQC5Sign setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblQC6 setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblQC6Sign setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblQC7 setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblQCSign setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblQC8 setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblQC8Sign setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblQC9 setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblQC9Sign setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblQTitleKiwiSaver setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD];
  //        
  //        [lblQK1 setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblKiwiContributePercent setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblQK1 setFrame:YOFFSET_FRAME_iPAD(lblQK1, 10, -)];
  //        
  //        [lblQK2 setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblKiwiContributeValue setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblKiwiContributeValue setFrame:YOFFSET_FRAME_iPAD(lblKiwiContributeValue, 23, -)];
  //        [lblQK2 setFrame:YOFFSET_FRAME_iPAD(lblQK2, 29, -)];
  //        
  //        [lblQK3 setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblKiwiCompulsoryValue setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT];
  //        [lblQK3 setFrame:YOFFSET_FRAME_iPAD(lblQK3, 45, -)];
  //        [lblKiwiCompulsoryValue setFrame:YOFFSET_FRAME_iPAD(lblKiwiCompulsoryValue, 39, -)];
  //        [imgvLast setFrame:YOFFSET_FRAME_iPAD(imgvLast, 32, -)];
  //        [lblQKLast setFont:LABEL_FONT_iPAD];
  ```

  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are changing the fonts of all the labels within the view why not give this a try

```
if([self isPad])
    {
        [btnReset.titleLabel setFont:BUTTON_FONT_iPAD_BOLD];
        [btnViewReport.titleLabel setFont:BUTTON_FONT_iPAD_BOLD];
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(768,1200);
        for(UILabel *label in [self.view subviews]) {
           if([label isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) 
           label.font = LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT;
        }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic it works great without taking the outlets...Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Stuff them all in an array, then do `[yourArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setFont:) withObject:LABEL_FONT_iPAD_REPORT]`.

Comment: Chuck's answer certainly works but what you're trying to do sounds really awful and really isn't the best way (or best use of your time) to do a Universal iOS app.  

You should do a second xib file for iPad alongside the first xib which targets iPhone.

There are lots of tutorials and related questions [like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271442/universal-ipad-iphone-xibs-xcode-4) which cover the subject of doing parallel xibs for iPad and iPhone.

Comment: Nice solution but still i have to take all the outlets!!! Taking too many outlets is not a good way that I think!!!1

Comment: @Michael Deutermann: Very true. I should have mentioned that, but I was in too much of a hurry.